# Using concat rather than push in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, concatenation

I am working on setting up redux in my React project and wanted to confirm something regarding avoiding mutating state.

When one needs to add a new element to an array, my understanding is that one should use something like `concat`, rather than `push`, because even if one first uses the spread operator to copy an array, the new array will still point to the same location in memory as the original array. So when one then uses `push` on the new array, it's still mutating the original. Therefore, one should use `concat`, which, unlike `push`, won't touch the original array.

Therefore instead of this:

```
case 'CREATE_STORY':
  newState = [
    ...state,
  ]
  newState.push(action.payload);
  return newState;
```

One should do something like this:

```
case 'CREATE_STORY':
  newState = [
    ...state,
  ]
  newState.concat([action.payload]);
  return newState;
```

Is that correct?

Comment: no, if you use the spread operator it will point to a different place in memory. if you do `const a = [...b]` then  `a === b` will be false

Comment: @buzatto, because arrays are by reference, I'm thinking it creates a new pointer pointing to the same thing as the original.

Comment: @buzatto - that's the way redux needs to work - never mutate, always return a new reference.

Comment: @adam I'm aware of that, but spread operator creates a shallow copy from a given object. if it returns the same location in memory then my example `a===b` should return true, not false like it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> because even if one first uses the spread operator to copy an array, the new array will still point to the same location in memory as the original array. So when one then uses push on the new array, it's still mutating the original.

It's incorrect, you won't mutate the original state, therefore this code is valid:

```
const newState = [...state];
newState.push(action.payload);
// newState !== state, will render as expected
return newState;
```

But usually, it's better not to use `.push` or any mutating functions at all ("code smell", may lead to bugs if not used carefully). That's because in React we should treat everything as immutable, see [the power of not mutating data](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data) in docs.

---

The problem with `.concat` is that you never remember what this function does (it returns a shallow copy?). So basically you want to write a consistent code that you will understand immediately.

You want to add a new element to an array? Use spread syntax:

```
return [...state, action.payload]
```

Comment: The first part of what you wrote makes sense to me. But regarding the second part, if you have already created a new array with the spread operator, in what sense is original data being mutated at all by using `push()` on the new array? How can that be a problem in and of itself?

Comment: It won't but one can forget to make a copy beforehand, which is error prone

Comment: Yes, I agree with that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it in one line

```
return newState.concat([action.payload]);
```

because concat only returns a concated array, and won't change your newState

Answer (score 0):

Personal preference only, if your state is an array and you need to change it, I find it more succint to do things in one line instead of creating variables like `newState`

```js
 case REMOVE_ITEM:
    return state.filter(item => item !== action.payload);

 case APPEND_ITEM:
    return [...state, action.payload]

 case CHANGE_ITEM:
    return state.map(item => item === action.payload.oldItem ? action.payload.newItem : item)
```

Comment: Agreed. This looks cleaner.